# Finding positive integer(s) $n$ for which $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} | 3^{n} + 5^{n}$: Is my solution correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

The problem is the following

> Find all positive integers $n$ such that $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}$ divides $3^{n} + 5^{n}$.

And I attempted as the following:
As  $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}\ |\ 3^{n} + 5^{n}$,
$$3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}\ |\ 3^{n} + 5^{n} - 5(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}) = -2\cdot 3 ^ {n-1}$$
And
$$3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}\ |\ 3^{n} + 5^{n} - 3(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}) = 2\cdot 5 ^ {n-1}$$
These expressions say that
$$2\cdot 3 ^ {n-1} = p(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}) \quad \textrm{for some odd} \  p \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
And
$$2\cdot 5 ^ {n-1} = q(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}) \quad \textrm{for some odd} \  q \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
By addition, it becomes clear that $q = 2 - p$.
Hence, the last expression is equivalent to $2\cdot 5 ^ {n-1} = (2 - p)(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1})$.
Solving for $p$, it is equal to $\frac{2\cdot3^{n-1}}{3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}}$.
Here, $p$ is odd only for $n = 1$, hence it is the only solution.

Is this attempt a solution for the problem? And for the effort, Thanks!

Comment: From $q=2-p$ and $p,q \in \mathbb Z^+$ it is already clear that $p=q=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}\ |\ 3^{n} + 5^{n} - 5(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}) = -2\cdot 3 ^ {n-1}$?

Comment: @SunShine It means $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}\ |\ -2\cdot 3 ^ {n-1}$.

Comment: Please [search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%243%5E%7Bn-1%7D%2B5%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cmid3%5En%2B5%5En%24) before posting questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I needed solution verification, I knew the alternatives.

Comment: Generally you can determine that by comparing to the *many* other soliutions. If not then you should ask a question about *precisely* which step you have doubts, not  a generic "is this a solution"?  This way helps you learn better, and also helps to improve our prior answers if you point out parts that are not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is mostly correct, but your argument that $p = \frac{2\cdot3^{n-1}}{3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}}$ is only odd for $n = 1$ is not true since for *all* odd $n$, the result is either not an integer or it's an odd integer. Instead, $p$ is odd, as you stated, but with $2 - p \gt 0$ from $2\cdot 5 ^ {n-1} = (2 - p)(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1})$ since the left side is positive, the right side must be as well, means only $p = 1$ works. Thus, $2\cdot 3 ^ {n-1} = p(3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1})$ gives $3^{n-1} = 5^{n-1} \implies n = 1$, so your solution is correct.

A somewhat easier way to see this is that, from what you wrote, $3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} \mid -2\cdot 3^{n-1} \implies 3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} \le \left|-2\cdot 3^{n-1}\right| = 2\cdot 3^{n-1}$. For $n \gt 1$, we have $5^{n-1} \gt 3^{n-1} \implies 3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1} \gt 2\cdot 3^{n-1}$, so only $n = 1$ is a possible solution. Since $n = 1$ gives $2 \mid 8$, this means only $n = 1$ works.

Comment: I think because $2\cdot 3^{n-1} \lt 3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}$, that is why it is odd only for $n=1$. (which I used in my argument)

Comment: @BookOfFlames Thank you for clarifying. With $2\cdot 3^{n-1} \lt 3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}$ (for $n \gt 1$), this means the result is only an integer for $n = 1$, with it having $p$ being odd only because the integer result is $1$. Since you didn't explicitly state $2\cdot 3^{n-1} \lt 3^{n-1} + 5^{n-1}$, I assumed your statement about $p$ being odd was referring to the denominator having only $1$ factor of $2$, which happens for all odd $n$, not just $n = 1$.